# DirectoryInfo.GetFiles shows wrong number of files

Tags: c#, file, directory

I am using `DirectoryInfo` to count the number of files on a network directory:

```
public static void foo(path)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    dir.Refresh();
    int numOfFiles = dir.GetFiles().Length;
}
```

I'm encountering a problem that the number of files is incorrect: the method always show the **previous** number of files since the method was called:

If the directory has `123` files, then `numOfFiles = 0` files.

If the directory has `345` files, it shows `numOfFiles = 123` files.

If the directory has `678` files, it shows `numOfFiles = 345` files, etc.

Any ideas about this? Is it because this method is `static`? Is it network location related?

Comment: Have you checked if there are folders? folders != files

Comment: There are no folders under this directory.

Comment: Are there different Threads that are using this method?

Comment: No other threads.

Comment: Instantiate `dir` outside of your method and give it a hard coded path, see if it does the same.

Comment: I cannot do that @JayGould because it recieves a param which us part of the path.

Comment: Have you tried `Directory.GetFiles` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should work as expected:

```
int counts = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
```